# module load command in linux bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, environment-modules

I need to execute Python script in HPC cluster. Unfortunately, the default python version is just 2.6.6 and there is no numpy and scipy.

I can load these modules in command line

```
#module load /home/hw1u16/modules/2.7.3
```

and

```
module load /home/hw1u16/modules/1.6.2
```

However, when I write the bash script like this

```
module load /home/hw1u16/modules/2.7.3
module load /home/hw1u16/modules/1.6.2
python /home/hw1u16/project/trainAgent.py
```

It warns me

`ModuleCmd_Load.c(200):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for '/home/hw1u16/modules'
ModuleCmd_Load.c(200):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for '/home/hw1u16/modules'`

I don't know what's wrong, could any guys help me?

Comment: Please let me know if this works :)

Comment: The `/modules/` in `module load /home/hw1u16/modules/1.6.2` looks a little off. Are you sure it's not `module load /home/hw1u16/python-2.6` or something like that?

Comment: Actually, I copy the file from the original file from the path shown in "module avail" command. I can execute like "module load python/2.7.3" on the shell terminal. But it's still useless in the bash script. Maybe I need some special setting?

Comment: @skwang see updated answer, please let me know

Comment: The error means there is no module file available in the path

Comment: I have found the fault. Coz I write the script in windows computer and scp it to the remote, function module cannot parse the path string formatted in windows. Thx all.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, and found two solutions:

1. instead of running your script with `sh yourscript.sh` or `./yourscript.sh`, you could run it as `. yourscript.sh` This will source the module correctly and run the script
2. if you don't want to use `. yourscript.sh`, you can modify your shebang from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` as noted in DavidC's answer and run your script as `./yourscript.sh` Note that running it as `sh yourscript.sh` will not work

Comment: The shebang solution did not work for me (it also doesn't seem to be something DavidC said). The first solution worked great though. Didn't realise `.` was an alias for `source`.

Comment: Same as @JoshuaPerrett, solution 1 works for me, solution 2 doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I think I know where is the problem. Try `type module` from the shell to see how `module` it is currently defined in your system. You will receive two options: either it is an alias or a function. This is because the `module` command is an `alias` or `shell function`.

Say your script is the following `running.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash  
module load python/2.7.3
python /home/hw1u16/project/trainAgent.py
```

(It is a good practice to add the shebang)

To sort out this problem you have two options:

- Option 1:

`source` the  scitpt. In other words, do: `source running.sh`. This is exactly the same as typing the `module` command directly into your interactive shell.  However, by doing `./running.sh`, you are running a new, non-interactive shell.  These generally do not have the standard aliases and shell functions set up.

- Option 2:

Find the initialization script that defines the `module` command and `source` it from the script

Comment: I have tried the `source` command, seems `module avail` can be use in bash script, but when I write `module load gcc/4.6.2` or `module load python/2.7.3`. It warns me `'ython(9):ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'python/2.7.3'. `
`

Comment: @skwang This is the same error you reported before. Please, after writing the script as I wrote in the answer, _do_ `source running.sh` and then `./running.sh` in the same terminal